# Exception caught by widgets library: Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget

Tags: flutter

The same 2 errors appear in 2 different files when I run my flutter program, does anyone know how to fix this?   this is my code

code for list restaurant.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:resto_app/data/model/restaurant_list.dart';
import 'package:resto_app/ui/detail_page.dart';

class CardRestaurant extends StatelessWidget {
  final Restaurant restaurant;

  const CardRestaurant({Key? key, required this.restaurant}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: InkWell(
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
            return RestaurantDetailPage(idrestaurant: restaurant.id);
          }));
        },
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              margin:
                  const EdgeInsets.only(left: 40, top: 5, right: 20, bottom: 5),
              height: 170.0,
              width: double.infinity,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.lime.shade100,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
              ),
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                    left: 200, top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 20),
                child: Expanded(
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      SizedBox(
                        width: 120.0,
                        child: Expanded(child: Text(restaurant.name)),
                      ),
                      _sizebox(10),
                      Row(
                        children: [
                          _icon(Icons.star_rate, 20, Colors.yellow),
                          Text(
                            ' ${restaurant.rating}',
                          ),
                        ],
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
              left: 20.0,
              top: 15.0,
              bottom: 15.0,
              child: ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                child: Hero(
                  tag: restaurant.pictureId,
                  child: Image.network(
                    "https://restaurant-api.dicoding.dev/images/small/" +
                        restaurant.pictureId,
                    width: 200,
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Widget _sizebox(double height) {
  return SizedBox(
    height: height,
  );
}

Widget _icon(IconData icon, double size, Color color) {
  return Icon(
    icon,
    size: size,
    color: color,
  );
}
```

and my detailrestaurant.dart code

`

```
`import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:resto_app/data/model/restaurants_detail.dart';
import 'package:resto_app/common/constant.dart';

class RestaurantDetail extends StatelessWidget {
  static const routeName = '/restaurant_detail';
  final Restaurant restaurant;
  const RestaurantDetail({Key? key, required this.restaurant})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Hero(
                tag: restaurant.pictureId,
                child: Image.network(
                  "https://restaurant-api.dicoding.dev/images/medium/" +
                      restaurant.pictureId,
                ),
              ),
              Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            Text(restaurant.name),
                            _sizebox(10),
                            Row(
                              children: [
                                _icon(Icons.location_city, 20, Colors.grey),
                                const SizedBox(
                                  width: 10,
                                ),
                                Column(
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                  children: [
                                    Text(restaurant.city),
                                    Text(restaurant.address),
                                  ],
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        Row(
                          children: [
                            _icon(Icons.star_rate, 20, Colors.yellow),
                            Text(
                              ' ${restaurant.rating}',
                            ),
                          ],
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  _barrierContent(),
                  Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        padding:
                            const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, right: 20, left: 20),
                        child: Text('Description'),
                      ),
                      Container(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                              top: 10, right: 20, left: 20, bottom: 20),
                          width: double.infinity,
                          child: Text(restaurant.description)),
                    ],
                  ),
                  _barrierContent(),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                        vertical: 10, horizontal: 20),
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Text('Category'),
                        ListBody(
                          children: restaurant.categories.map((food) {
                            return Text(
                              '- ${food.name}',
                            );
                          }).toList(),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  _barrierContent(),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                        vertical: 10, horizontal: 20),
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Text('Menu Food'),
                        ListBody(
                          children: restaurant.menus.foods.map((categori) {
                            return Text(
                              '- ${categori.name}',
                            );
                          }).toList(),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  _barrierContent(),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                        vertical: 10, horizontal: 20),
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Text('Menu Drink'),
                        ListBody(
                          children: restaurant.menus.drinks.map((drink) {
                            return Text('- ${drink.name}');
                          }).toList(),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  _barrierContent(),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                        vertical: 10, horizontal: 10),
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Text('Comment'),
                        ListBody(
                          children: restaurant.customerReviews.map((review) {
                            return Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                              child: Expanded(
                                child: Row(children: [
                                  Container(
                                    width: 40,
                                    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                                        shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                        color: Colors.blue),
                                    child: Center(
                                        child: Text(
                                      review.name.characters.elementAt(0),
                                      style: const TextStyle(
                                          color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
                                    )),
                                  ),
                                  const SizedBox(
                                    width: 15,
                                  ),
                                  Expanded(
                                    child: Column(
                                      crossAxisAlignment:
                                          CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                      children: [
                                        Row(
                                          children: [
                                            Text(
                                              review.name,
                                              style: const TextStyle(
                                                  fontSize: 16,
                                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                            ),
                                            Text(
                                              ' ${review.date}',
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                  fontSize: 14,
                                                  color: Colors.grey.shade500),
                                            )
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                        SizedBox(
                                          width: 270,
                                          child: Text(
                                            review.review,
                                            maxLines: 2,
                                            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                          ),
                                        )
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  )
                                ]),
                              ),
                            );
                          }).toList(),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  _barrierContent()
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Widget _barrierContent() {
  return Container(
    height: 10,
    color: Colors.grey.shade200,
  );
}

Widget _sizebox(double height) {
  return SizedBox(
    height: height,
  );
}

Widget _icon(IconData icon, double size, Color color) {
  return Icon(
    icon,
    size: size,
    color: color,
  );
}
```

`

``

error
The same 2 errors appear in 2 different files when I run my flutter program, does anyone know how to fix this?

[image: Error]

Answer (score 0):

```
child: Expanded(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 120.0,
                    child: Expanded(child: Text(restaurant.name)),
                  ),
```

parent of `Expanded` must be `Stack, Column, Row` but in your example it's wrong

Answer (score 0):

You should use **Expanded** only within a **Column, Row or Flex** & that to its **top most child only**

Here you have use Expanded widget inside padding widget  which is inside stack and also you can't use Expanded inside stack, so it causing this **ParentDataWidget** Error

**code for list restaurant.dart**

```
    class CardRestaurant extends StatelessWidget {
  final Restaurant restaurant;

  const CardRestaurant({Key? key, required this.restaurant}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: InkWell(
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
            return RestaurantDetailPage(idrestaurant: restaurant.id);
          }));
        },
        child: Stack( //---------------
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              margin:
                  const EdgeInsets.only(left: 40, top: 5, right: 20, bottom: 5),
              height: 170.0,
              width: double.infinity,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.lime.shade100,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
              ),
              child: Padding(//---------
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                    left: 200, top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 20),
                child: Expanded(//--------- you can't use expanded inside Stack 
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      SizedBox(
                        width: 120.0,
                        child: Expanded(child: Text(restaurant.name)),
                      ),
                      _sizebox(10),
```

**and my detailrestaurant.dart code**

```
class RestaurantDetail extends StatelessWidget {
  static const routeName = '/restaurant_detail';
  final Restaurant restaurant;
  const RestaurantDetail({Key? key, required this.restaurant})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Hero(
                tag: restaurant.pictureId,
                child: Image.network(
                  "https://restaurant-api.dicoding.dev/images/medium/" +
                      restaurant.pictureId,
                ),
              ),
              Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            Text(restaurant.name),
                            _sizebox(10),
                            Row(
                              children: [
                                _icon(Icons.location_city, 20, Colors.grey),
                                const SizedBox(
                                  width: 10,
                                ),
                                Column(
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                  children: [
                                    Text(restaurant.city),
                                    Text(restaurant.address),
                                  ],
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        Row(
                          children: [
                            _icon(Icons.star_rate, 20, Colors.yellow),
                            Text(
                              ' ${restaurant.rating}',
                            ),
                          ],
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  _barrierContent(),
                  Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        padding:
                            const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, right: 20, left: 20),
                        child: Text('Description'),
                      ),
                      Container(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                              top: 10, right: 20, left: 20, bottom: 20),
                          width: double.infinity,
                          child: Text(restaurant.description)),
                    ],
                  ),
                  _barrierContent(),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                        vertical: 10, horizontal: 20),
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Text('Category'),
                        ListBody(
                          children: restaurant.categories.map((food) {
                            return Text(
                              '- ${food.name}',
                            );
                          }).toList(),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  _barrierContent(),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                        vertical: 10, horizontal: 20),
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Text('Menu Food'),
                        ListBody(
                          children: restaurant.menus.foods.map((categori) {
                            return Text(
                              '- ${categori.name}',
                            );
                          }).toList(),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  _barrierContent(),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                        vertical: 10, horizontal: 20),
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Text('Menu Drink'),
                        ListBody(
                          children: restaurant.menus.drinks.map((drink) {
                            return Text('- ${drink.name}');
                          }).toList(),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  _barrierContent(),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                        vertical: 10, horizontal: 10),
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Text('Comment'), 
                        ListBody(//--- this is top most child
                          children: restaurant.customerReviews.map((review) {
                            return Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                              child: Expanded(//--------- This causing problem here, you can only use Exapnded to column top most child
                                child: Row(children: [
                                  Container(
                                    width: 40,
                                    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                                        shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                        color: Colors.blue),
                                    child: Center(
                                        child: Text(
                                      review.name.characters.elementAt(0),
                                      style: const TextStyle(
                                          color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
                                    )),
                                  ),
                                  const SizedBox(
                                    width: 15,
                                  ),
                                  Expanded(//---- This one also causing Problem
                                    child: Column(
                                      crossAxisAlignment:
                                          CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                      children: [
                                        Row(
                                          children: [
                                            Text(
                                              review.name,
                                              style: const TextStyle(
                                                  fontSize: 16,
                                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                            ),
                                            Text(
                                              ' ${review.date}',
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                  fontSize: 14,
                                                  color: Colors.grey.shade500),
                                            )
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                        SizedBox(
                                          width: 270,
                                          child: Text(
                                            review.review,
                                            maxLines: 2,
                                            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                          ),
                                        )
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  )
                                ]),
                              ),
                            );
                          }).toList(),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  _barrierContent()
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Keep this point in mind to avoid basic error

1. Most common one **Expanded** can only use to a **descendant of Column,Row & Flex**
2. Don't use **Positioned** under **Row or Column** instead use Align
3. Under **ListView** don't use **Spacer** instead use SizedBox

Hope this might help you to solve your Error

Happy Learning!!!